# Implementing same interface in multiple Fragments, called from Activity.

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

In my `Activity`'s `onActivityForResult()` I want to do something like this:

```
OnReturnFromProfile mCallback;
mCallback.onReturnFromProfile(extras);
```

I have this defined globally as a standalone file:

```
public interface OnReturnFromProfile {
    public void onReturnFromProfile(Bundle extras);
}
```

Now several `Fragment`s can grab data from the `Activity`'s `onActivityForResult()` and I want each `Fragment` to implement this `interface`.

Obviously there is a major design flaw here.  The `mCallback` does not know which implementation of the interface to call.

What is the proper way to handle this situation?  It seems the long way is to make this `interface` in each `Fragment` but now I have like 5 duplicate `interface`s.  And then the code gets messy because in the `Activity` I'd have to pass around the `Fragment` `tag` in some long condition statement.

*Is this the only way?
Do I need to even use an interface?*

**In depth context here on the flow:**

`Fragment` A (attached to `Activity` A) has a list with a `RecyclerView`.  When you click on a list row, it opens `Activity` B (using `startActivityWithResult()`).  In `Activity` B you can do stuff that affects the list (just mentioned).  So naturally, I want to update the list when `Activity` B is closed.  I can get the result now in `Activity` A.  The problem is -- where to route it?  I have `Fragment`'s A, B, C, D and E that can all attach to `Activity` A and do similar actions on the list.  So my intent (no pun intended) was to minimize code with a single `interface` callback (which I am not sure is even possible).

As I type type this, I am starting to realize I *might* have a bigger architecture problem if I have 5 lists with the same actions and datatypes?  They do have subtle differences though.

Comment: Could you put one of your fragments?

Comment: You can use EventBus sticky events or create BaseFragment and extend it for each Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The Fragments do not have to define the Interface.  The Interface can be defined once elsewhere.  Each Fragment can simply implement the interface.

In fact a Fragment which does not need to know the "onReturnFromProfile()" event has occurred does not need to implement the interface.

The Activity can:

```
if(fragment instanceof OnReturnFromProfile) {
  (OnReturnFromProfile)fragment.onReturnFromProfile();
}
```

Note that casting the object to be a reference to the Interface solves the "which implementation of the interface?" problem.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.  This looks like this will have the least code impact to what I am doing now

Comment: So this is close, but I got it working with the `Fragment` name, instead of 
 casting to `OnReturnFromProfile`

Comment: As long as you know which Fragment to cast to, fine, but if you don't know which Fragment is visible, casting to the interface should work.

Comment: Oh I see.  So you don't have to chain a long condition of fragments.  I tried this but it said undefined method.  Can you show how you get the fragment variable? I'm using findFragmentById().